# using knockout paged grid in durandal

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, durandal, single-page-application

I created a single page app using durandal and the knockout paged grid in this example 
http://knockoutjs.com/examples/grid.html.

My Question is how will I be able to get the values on a selected row. I tried the following steps but nothing happened. On the attached event of my viewmodel i have this command.

```
$(view).find('.table tbody>tr').on('click', function (event) {
    $(view).find('.table tbody>tr').addClass('success')
           .siblings().removeClass('success');          
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Durandal samples already has the knockout examples integrated e.g. http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-2.0/#knockout-samples/pagedGrid so that might be a better starting point.

Please take a look at some of the knockout documentation at http://learn.knockoutjs.com to figure out why it's a good idea NOT to use jQuery for things that are better handled in knockout. Especially read about click binding http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html.
Once you got your app working that way read http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/11/revisit-event-delegation-in-knockout-js.html and upgrade your solution to use it.

Comment: The challenge now is getting the value of the selected table row. when button is clicked.          <tr class="selectablerow">
                    <td data-bind="text: Title"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: BcReference"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: Citation"></td>
                    <td style="width: 130px; padding: 5px">
                        <a class="btn btn-danger download" title="download" data-bind="click: $root.GetselectedRow">                           
                        </a>                       
                    </td>
                </tr>

Comment: By default `GetSelectedRow` will have the data passed in as first argument. Read http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html again ;-)